# bigchaindb-driver not found in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, blockchain, bigchaindb

I am trying to use Node.js SDK for BigchainDB but I always get error as

> Error: Cannot find module 'bigchaindb-driver'

But `bigchaindb-driver` is already installed by `npm install`.

Please check this [github issue](https://github.com/bigchaindb/js-bigchaindb-driver/issues/296)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error and I resolved it by down grading `bigchaindb-driver` to 4.1.0 and also installing `base-x` version 3.0.4 and `bip39` version ^2.5.0".

Following commands can resolve your error:

```
npm install bigchaindb-driver@4.1.0
npm install base-x@3.0.4
npm install bip39@2.5.0
```